# How can I run Java classes without -cp

Tags: java, cmd, terminal, classpath

In my command prompt (on Windows 10), I can run javac with any java file just fine. But, when I go to run the created class with "java [classname]" I get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class [class name]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [classname]
```

I used to be able to run just the command "java [classname]" and it ran AOK, but now it's not working and I need "java -cp . [classname]" instead. Why? Is there a way around this?

Here's a bit of a timeline when I started having trouble:

- Had to isntall JUnit for my CS class, around where the issues started happening
- Had to install some Java extensions with VS code.

Answer (score 1):

The Java runtime shouldn't be impacted by installing JUnit or Java extensions in Visual Studio Code, however it's possible that any modifications to your classpath or environment variables contributed to the problem.

You can try telling the Java runtime to look for classes in the current directory by changing the CLASSPATH environment variable:

```
set CLASSPATH=.
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, in the style of Daniel's answer.

Turns out that when I installed JUnit, the instructions had me put CLASSPATH in my environment variables. Removing the CLASSPATH variable or changing it to "." let me run from my cmd again without specifying classpath, since I removed what was redirecting my classpath. Then all I had to do was close and reopen my terminal.